# list of schema with sizes (relative and absolute) in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a query that returns a result of the form for any database (see example below supposing total space used by the database is 40GB)

```
schema | size | relative size
----------+-------------------
foo    | 15GB |   37.5%      
bar    | 20GB |     50%
baz    |  5GB |   12.5%
```

I've managed to concoct a list of space using entities in the database sorted by schema, which has been useful, but getting a summary per schema from this doesn't look so easy. See below.

```
SELECT relkind,
       relname,
       pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid))
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
       INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace
         ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
ORDER  BY pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname,
          pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) DESC;
```

This gives results like

```
  relkind |                relname                |      nspname       | pg_size_pretty 
---------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+----------------
  r       | geno                                  | btsnp              | 11 GB
  i       | geno_pkey                             | btsnp              | 5838 MB
  r       | anno                                  | btsnp              | 63 MB
  i       | anno_fid_key                          | btsnp              | 28 MB
  i       | ix_btsnp_anno_rsid                    | btsnp              | 28 MB
  [...]
  r       | anno                                  | btsnp_shard        | 63 MB
  r       | geno4681                              | btsnp_shard        | 38 MB
  r       | geno4595                              | btsnp_shard        | 38 MB
  r       | geno4771                              | btsnp_shard        | 38 MB
  r       | geno4775                              | btsnp_shard        | 38 MB
```

It looks like using an aggregation operator like SUM may be necessary, no success with that thus far.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT schema_name, 
       sum(table_size),
       (sum(table_size) / database_size) * 100
FROM (
  SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname as schema_name,
         pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as table_size,
         sum(pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid)) over () as database_size
  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
     JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
) t
GROUP BY schema_name, database_size
```

Edit: just noticed the workaround with summing up all tables to get the database size is not necessary:

```sql
SELECT schema_name, 
       pg_size_pretty(sum(table_size)::bigint),
       (sum(table_size) / pg_database_size(current_database())) * 100
FROM (
  SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname as schema_name,
         pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as table_size
  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
     JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
) t
GROUP BY schema_name
ORDER BY schema_name
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The JOIN above is equivalent to INNER JOIN, yes?

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it is possible to truncate the percent values to two decimal places, say.

Comment: One can do - trunc((sum(table_size) / pg_database_size(current_database())) * 100, 2) AS percent. Thanks to merlin83 on #postgresql.

Comment: @Faheem: yes, JOIN and INNER JOIN are equivalent

Comment: This still works! Just want to add that this includes index sizes as well. Actually the column "table_size" from the subquery "t" is actually "object size", because in includes indexes, sequences, views, materialized views etc, as indicated in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-class.html

Comment: When I use this query I get what I want, but sum of the percentages of the schemas is not 100. So, there must be other database objects or am I missing something else? If I do not miss anything what are those other objects and how can I find their sizes?

Answer (score 12):

Better solution:

```
WITH 

schemas AS (
SELECT schemaname as name, sum(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename)))::bigint as size FROM pg_tables
GROUP BY schemaname
),

db AS (
SELECT pg_database_size(current_database()) AS size
)

SELECT schemas.name, 
       pg_size_pretty(schemas.size) as absolute_size,
       schemas.size::float / (SELECT size FROM db)  * 100 as relative_size
FROM schemas;
```

The accepted answer solves the described problem, but the suggested query is not efficient. You can do EXPLAIN to see the difference:

```
EXPLAIN WITH 

schemas AS (
SELECT schemaname as name, sum(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename)))::bigint as size FROM pg_tables
GROUP BY schemaname
),

db AS (SELECT pg_database_size(current_database()) AS size)

SELECT schemas.name, 
       pg_size_pretty(schemas.size) as absolute_size,
       schemas.size::float / (SELECT size FROM db)  * 100 as relative_size
FROM schemas;

                                                 QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTE Scan on schemas  (cost=47100.79..47634.34 rows=16417 width=104)
   CTE schemas
     ->  Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=46854.50..47100.76 rows=16417 width=72)
           Group Key: n.nspname
           ->  Gather  (cost=43119.63..46608.25 rows=32834 width=96)
                 Workers Planned: 2
                 ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=42119.63..42324.85 rows=16417 width=96)
                       Group Key: n.nspname
                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=744.38..39763.93 rows=94228 width=128)
                             Hash Cond: (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pg_class c  (cost=0.00..38772.14 rows=94228 width=72)
                                   Filter: (relkind = ANY ('{r,p}'::"char"[]))
                             ->  Hash  (cost=539.17..539.17 rows=16417 width=68)
                                   ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace n  (cost=0.00..539.17 rows=16417 width=68)
   CTE db
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
   InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
     ->  CTE Scan on db  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=8)
```

vs

```
EXPLAIN SELECT schema_name, 
       pg_size_pretty(sum(table_size)::bigint),
       (sum(table_size) / pg_database_size(current_database())) * 100
FROM (
  SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname as schema_name,
         pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as table_size
  FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
     JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
) t
GROUP BY schema_name
ORDER BY schema_name; 

                                       QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=283636.24..334759.75 rows=1202906 width=128)
   Group Key: pg_namespace.nspname
   ->  Sort  (cost=283636.24..286643.51 rows=1202906 width=72)
         Sort Key: pg_namespace.nspname
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=744.38..51446.15 rows=1202906 width=72)
               Hash Cond: (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
               ->  Seq Scan on pg_class  (cost=0.00..44536.06 rows=1202906 width=8)
               ->  Hash  (cost=539.17..539.17 rows=16417 width=68)
                     ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace  (cost=0.00..539.17 rows=16417 width=68)
```

Comment: @k-server first query is efficient as compared to later one but the answer returned by both of these queries is completely different.  the number returned in the later query we are getting high value as compared to the first query.

Comment: Very fast, for a 90K tables in 150 schemas, it took less than 10 seconds instead of 3.5minutes. But the other solution uses pg_class which is more complete than pg_tables as it includes indexes that take considerable disk space too.

Answer (score 6):

https://www.depesz.com/2018/02/17/which-schema-is-using-the-most-disk-space/

shows a solution that counts the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) tabels as well. Tested on PG12:

```
 WITH recursive all_elements AS (
    SELECT 'base/' || l.filename AS path, x.*
    FROM
        pg_ls_dir('base/') AS l (filename),
        LATERAL pg_stat_file( 'base/' || l.filename) AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'pg_tblspc/' || l.filename AS path, x.*
    FROM
        pg_ls_dir('pg_tblspc/') AS l (filename),
        LATERAL pg_stat_file( 'pg_tblspc/' || l.filename) AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        u.path || '/' || l.filename, x.*
    FROM
        all_elements u,
        lateral pg_ls_dir(u.path) AS l(filename),
        lateral pg_stat_file( u.path || '/' || l.filename ) AS x
    WHERE
        u.isdir
), all_files AS (
    SELECT path, SIZE FROM all_elements WHERE NOT isdir
), interesting_files AS (
    SELECT
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(f.path, '.*/', ''),
            '\.[0-9]*$',
            ''
        ) AS filename,
        SUM( f.size )
    FROM
        pg_database d,
        all_files f
    WHERE
        d.datname = current_database() AND
        f.path ~ ( '/' || d.oid || E'/[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$' )
    GROUP BY filename
)
SELECT
    n.nspname AS schema_name,
    SUM( f.sum ) AS total_schema_size
FROM
    interesting_files f
    JOIN pg_class c ON f.filename::oid = c.relfilenode
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class dtc ON dtc.reltoastrelid = c.oid AND c.relkind = 't'
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON COALESCE( dtc.relnamespace, c.relnamespace ) = n.oid
GROUP BY
    n.nspname
ORDER BY
    total_schema_size DESC
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Unable to run this on AWS RDS due to permissions :(

Comment: This solution requires superuser permissions, which is not available on some managed/hosted databases (Azure, for example)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find size of specific schema, you can simply use below query:

```
select sum(
    pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(schemaname) || 
    '.' || 
    quote_ident(tablename))
)::bigint 
from pg_tables where schemaname = 'mySchema';
```

Answer (score 1):

A minor extension to the above accepted answer, if all data are not in the default locations.

```
SELECT t.schema_name,
       pg_size_pretty(t.sum_size::bigint) sum_size_pretty,
       t.sum_size * 100 / pg_database_size(current_database()) space_pct,
       tsp.spcname,
       pg_tablespace_location(tsp.oid) --pg_default is 'base' pg_global is 'global'
FROM (
    SELECT nsp.nspname as schema_name,
           sum(pg_relation_size(cl.oid)) sum_size,
           cl.reltablespace
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class cl
       INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = cl.relnamespace
    GROUP BY schema_name, reltablespace
) t
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database db ON db.datname = current_database()
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace tsp ON
    tsp.oid = case when t.reltablespace<>0
                   then t.reltablespace
                   else db.dattablespace end
ORDER BY 1
```

(Left join for the case reltablespace get other reserved values than 0 in the future)

Comment: @Rahn, Could you please share query to fetch like schema_name,table_name,,table_size, tablespace_name,tablespace_location so that i can move some tables which is large in size to other mount point.  thanks