# How to fix database error '[Errno 28] No space left on device' in odoo

Tags: python, linux, odoo, odoo-14

I get this error when I try to do an odoo datbase backup with filestore

```
Database backup error: [(u'/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/proddb/4b/4b8718e76afe51cf49d5522ef03a3de3540f0ebb', u'/tmp/tmpVq0gWP/filestore/4b/4b8718e76afe51cf49d5522ef03a3de3540f0ebb', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'),
```

I have increased the disk space of the server, yet this does not solve the issue.
I ran df -h and it gave me this result

```
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M   82M  718M  11% /run
/dev/vda1       155G  124G   32G  80% /
tmpfs           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1004
```

Comment: Sounds like you still dont have enough storage. What is the free disk space or backup space?

Comment: What exactly does "I have increased the specification" mean? What does it entail? What does `df -h` say about the filesystems? And please edit your question with the extra information ...

Comment: try t go into `/tmp` and try to create a file or copy a file to that folder.. if that works, make sure that the file you are copying to /tmp via your app is not bigger than the size of your whole /tmp folder.. do the same test with /opt/. Another thing you can try is change the settings within your app to not use /tmp directly but to use something like /opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/tmp

Comment: how do I change the settings to not use /tmp ? @Ron

Comment: How big is your database? What command are you using to create the backup, does it have any options that might affect here the backup is created?

Comment: @balmy I am using the normal odoo database backup with filestore

Answer (score 1):

Before giving you a downloadable file, Odoo will backup the database and the filestore (attachments, other files of odoo) usually as zip to `/tmp`. That means both zipped can be quite big.

To get a good hint on how big that might be, try to find out the size of the database (for example by one of [this ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907047/postgres-db-size-command)) and of course the size of your database's filestore.

After a successful and complete download, Odoo will delete that file.