# postgresql list and order tables by size

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How can I **list all the tables** of a PostgreSQL database and **order them by size**?

Comment: If you are using the command-line psql client then a simple `\d+` will show you this information, though unsorted.

Comment: Thanks. But I *need it* sorted, I have too many tables.

Comment: People looking for the same thing but for databases instead of tables : [here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907188/812102).

Comment: Re psql: start it with --echo-hidden and it will tell you the queries done for \d+ and other backslash commands. Easy to add sorting.

Answer (score 443, accepted):

```
select
  table_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))),
  pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by 3 desc;
```

This shows you the size of all tables in the schema `public` if you have multiple schemas, you might want to use:

```
select table_schema, table_name, pg_relation_size('"'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'"')
from information_schema.tables
order by 3
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/13157/3

List of all object size functions in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE).

Comment: It's table_schema, not schema_name. The first query was fine but you had already started typing something in your psql session, which caused a syntax error.

Comment: OK this code works: `select table_schema, table_name, pg_relation_size(table_schema||'.'||table_name)
from information_schema.tables
order by 3;
` thanks for help!

Comment: any idea what this dont work in my case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977776/why-cant-see-my-schema-size

Comment: @Sucrenoir: "does not work" is not a valid Postgres error message. The query in my answer does work for me: http://rextester.com/KGKPR49004

Comment: I get zero rows when I run the first query.  `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public';` yields zero rows even though `\dn` shows schema public.  Maybe a change in 9.5 caused this?

Comment: I had to use pg_table_size instead of pg_relation_size to get the actual size as some tables were showing smaller sizes for pg_relation_size. These tables had jsonb columns. Not sure why it was happening though.

Comment: You should use `pg_total_relation_size` to get the total size of the table **including its indexes** - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991566/1668200

Comment: You can also use `pg_indexes_size` to ge the size of the indexes associated with the table.

Answer (score 216):

This will show you the schema name, table name, size pretty and size (needed for sort).

```
SELECT
  schema_name,
  relname,
  pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS size,
  table_size

FROM (
       SELECT
         pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname           AS schema_name,
         relname,
         pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AS table_size

       FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
         JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
     ) t
WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
ORDER BY table_size DESC;
```

I build this based on the solutions from here [list of schema with sizes (relative and absolute) in a PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418403/list-of-schema-with-sizes-relative-and-absolute-in-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: This is damn useful; takes into account indexes also.

Comment: Can be useful to add relkind to this to explicitly identifying table or index

Comment: This is only working for the *public* scheme.

Comment: For me, pg_relation_size (line 11) only showed 8 kB on a table with a huge PickledObjectField; pg_total_relation_size showed more sensible 57 MB.
You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/41991380/118520 for details.

Comment: Change `pg_relation_size` to `pg_total_relation_size` to include indices!

Answer (score 67):

This will be more clear.

`pg_size_pretty(<numeric_value>)` - converts no.of bytes to human-readable format.

`pg_database_size(<db_name>)` - gets database size in *bytes*.

`pg_total_relation_size(<relation_name>)` - gets total size of table and its index in *bytes*.

`pg_relation_size(<relation_name>)` - gets relation (table/index) size in *bytes*.

`pg_indexes_size(<relation_name>)` - gets index size of the *relation* in *bytes*.

`current_database()` - gets the currently used database on which this query is being performed.

**Query:**

```
select current_database() as database,
       pg_size_pretty(total_database_size) as total_database_size,
       schema_name,
       table_name,
       pg_size_pretty(total_table_size) as total_table_size,
       pg_size_pretty(table_size) as table_size,
       pg_size_pretty(index_size) as index_size
       from ( select table_name,
                table_schema as schema_name,
                pg_database_size(current_database()) as total_database_size,
                pg_total_relation_size(table_name) as total_table_size,
                pg_relation_size(table_name) as table_size,
                pg_indexes_size(table_name) as index_size
                from information_schema.tables
                where table_schema=current_schema() and table_name like 'table_%'
                order by total_table_size
            ) as sizes;
```

**Result:**

```
 database  | total_database_size | schema_name | table_name | total_table_size | table_size | index_size
-----------+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------
 vigneshdb | 1586 MB             | corpdata    | table_aaa  | 16 kB            | 0 bytes    | 8192 bytes
 vigneshdb | 1586 MB             | corpdata    | table_bbb  | 24 kB            | 0 bytes    | 16 kB
 vigneshdb | 1586 MB             | corpdata    | table_ccc  | 640 kB           | 112 kB     | 488 kB
 vigneshdb | 1586 MB             | corpdata    | table_ddd  | 9760 kB          | 3152 kB    | 6568 kB
 vigneshdb | 1586 MB             | corpdata    | table_eee  | 1120 MB          | 311 MB     | 808 MB
```

The humanized format is represent in `bytes`, `kB`, `MB`, `GB`, and `TB`.

`bytes` to `kB` - begins from `10240 bytes`

`bytes` to `MB` - begins from `10485248 bytes` = `10239.5 kB` ~ `10 MB`

`bytes` to `GB` - begins from `10736893952 bytes` = `10239.5 MB` ~ `10 BG`

`bytes` to `TB` - begins from `10994579406848 bytes` = `10239.5 GB` ~ `10 TB`

All unit conversions starts from `10 + <unit>`.

For reference - [Postgres Official Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT)

Comment: This example does not work with uppercase table names

Comment: In more recent Postgres versions such as 12.4, this query gives an error - the fix is to [use quote_ident()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417941/992887) around the `table_name`.

Comment: It is `pg_indexes_size` not `pg_index_size`.

Comment: I get error: `function pg_total_relation_size(information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist. null` and after using `quote_ident()` I get empty result.

Answer (score 54):

I like following statement:

```
SELECT 
  table_name, 
  pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))), 
  pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
FROM 
  information_schema.tables
WHERE 
  table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY 
  pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) DESC
```

You can see total size in a pretty format, but it is ordered correctly too.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: This is so far the best one.

Comment: Great answer, better than those currently above it. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT
   relname as "Table",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size"
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

taken from here https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/ITDOC/Check+size+of+tables+and+objects+in+PostgreSQL+database

Answer (score 23):

I needed to find which tables use the most space.

Based on other answers, I used that query:

```
select table_name, pg_size_pretty( pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) )
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) desc
```

I get the following result:

```
table_name              pg_size_pretty
--------------------------------------
trade_binance           96 GB
closs_v2_binance_stash  46 GB
closs_bitfinex_stash    5725 MB
trade_bitfinex          5112 MB
...
api_requests            0 bytes
trade_huobi             0 bytes
```

I should have bought a bigger SSD.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "total_size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
    AND C.relkind <> 'i'
    AND nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  ;
```

Credit:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/52141-postgresql-how-to-show-table-sizes

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a breakdown in total, toast and index sizes use this:

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
, pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS INDEX
, pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
, pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS TABLE
FROM (
SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-COALESCE(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes 
FROM (
  SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS TABLE_NAME
          , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
          , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
          , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
          , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
      FROM pg_class c
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE relkind = 'r'
  ) a
) a ORDER BY total_bytes DESC;
```

Answer (score 7):

It can be easily done from `psql` console, see the [meta commands reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DE).

> Table Size: `\dt+`
>
> Database size `\l+`
>
> Index size: `\di+`

For table size, first connect the database using `\c db_name`.

Please Note: Above won't sort by size as OP asked, still it could help.

Comment: Can it show the sum?

Answer (score 6):

```
select table_name,n_live_tup, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
inner join pg_stat_user_tables  on table_name=relname
where table_schema = 'public'
order by 2 desc
```

Another alternative

Answer (score 6):

This query provides for each table:

- `total_size` - total size of table and indexes in human-readable format
- `data_size` - size of table itself
- `index_size` - size of indexes of that table
- `rows` - the number of rows in the table
- `total_row_size` - an approximate size of indexes and data for each row
- `row_size` - an approximate size of data for each row

[Execute in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/02318/56/0)

```sql
SELECT
  nspname                                               AS "schema",
  pg_class.relname                                      AS "table",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid))  AS "total_size",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(pg_class.oid))        AS "data_size",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(pg_class.oid))         AS "index_size",
  pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup                        AS "rows",
  pg_size_pretty(
    pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid) / 
    (pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup + 1)
  )                                                     AS "total_row_size",
  pg_size_pretty(
    pg_relation_size(pg_class.oid) / 
    (pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup + 1)
  )                                                     AS "row_size"
FROM 
  pg_stat_user_tables 
JOIN 
  pg_class
ON
  pg_stat_user_tables.relid = pg_class.oid
JOIN 
  pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ns
ON
  pg_class.relnamespace = ns.oid
-- WHERE
--   nspname = 'public'
ORDER BY 
  pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid) DESC;
```

***To filter by schema, uncomment the `WHERE` clause.***

To better understand the query:

`pg_size_pretty(<numeric_value>)` - converts number of bytes to human-readable format.

`pg_total_relation_size(<relation_id>)` - gets total size of table and its indexes in *bytes*.

`pg_relation_size(<relation_id>)` - gets relation (table/index) size in *bytes*.

`pg_indexes_size(<relation_id>)` - gets index size of the *relation* in *bytes*.

`pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup` - is the number of rows in the table.

Output may look like this:

```
   schema    |                table                | total_size | data_size  | index_size |  rows  | total_row_size |  row_size  
-------------+-------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------+------------
 public      | mp                                  | 66 MB      | 32 MB      | 34 MB      | 200659 | 344 bytes      | 167 bytes
 hdb_catalog | event_invocation_logs               | 18 MB      | 16 MB      | 1736 kB    |  11034 | 1667 bytes     | 1495 bytes
 hdb_catalog | event_log                           | 6760 kB    | 5032 kB    | 1608 kB    |  11038 | 627 bytes      | 466 bytes
 public      | links                               | 3208 kB    | 760 kB     | 2416 kB    |   7565 | 434 bytes      | 102 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_cron_event_invocation_logs      | 1712 kB    | 1464 kB    | 216 kB     |   1280 | 1368 bytes     | 1170 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_cron_events                     | 672 kB     | 208 kB     | 424 kB     |   1600 | 429 bytes      | 133 bytes
 public      | selectors_cache                     | 656 kB     | 48 kB      | 576 kB     |    333 | 2011 bytes     | 147 bytes
 public      | objects                             | 408 kB     | 120 kB     | 256 kB     |   1288 | 324 bytes      | 95 bytes
 public      | strings                             | 360 kB     | 96 kB      | 160 kB     |    451 | 815 bytes      | 217 bytes
 public      | promise_links                       | 328 kB     | 8192 bytes | 256 kB     |      0 | 328 kB         | 8192 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_metadata                        | 296 kB     | 48 kB      | 32 kB      |      1 | 148 kB         | 24 kB
 public      | bool_exp                            | 176 kB     | 16 kB      | 128 kB     |     24 | 7208 bytes     | 655 bytes
 public      | links__tables                       | 120 kB     | 0 bytes    | 112 kB     |      0 | 120 kB         | 0 bytes
 public      | numbers                             | 120 kB     | 0 bytes    | 112 kB     |      0 | 120 kB         | 0 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_schema_notifications            | 64 kB      | 8192 bytes | 16 kB      |      1 | 32 kB          | 4096 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_version                         | 48 kB      | 8192 bytes | 32 kB      |      1 | 24 kB          | 4096 bytes
 storage     | buckets                             | 32 kB      | 8192 bytes | 16 kB      |      1 | 16 kB          | 4096 bytes
 public      | reserved                            | 32 kB      | 8192 bytes | 16 kB      |      8 | 3640 bytes     | 910 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_source_catalog_version          | 32 kB      | 8192 bytes | 16 kB      |      1 | 16 kB          | 4096 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_scheduled_events                | 24 kB      | 0 bytes    | 16 kB      |      0 | 24 kB          | 0 bytes
 storage     | files                               | 24 kB      | 0 bytes    | 16 kB      |      0 | 24 kB          | 0 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_scheduled_event_invocation_logs | 16 kB      | 0 bytes    | 8192 bytes |      0 | 16 kB          | 0 bytes
 hdb_catalog | hdb_action_log                      | 16 kB      | 0 bytes    | 8192 bytes |      0 | 16 kB          | 0 bytes
(23 rows)
```

P.S.

I do +1 only to ignore `devision by zero` error, if you know a better way tell me about it.

More [functions in PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE).

Answer (score 5):

You can get total relation size and relation size, which may be different depending on your tables relationships.
Now here's how to get top 100 tables on your database:

```
SELECT schemaname                                    AS table_schema,
       relname                                       AS table_name,
       PG_SIZE_PRETTY(PG_TOTAL_RELATION_SIZE(relid)) AS total_size,
       PG_SIZE_PRETTY(PG_RELATION_SIZE(relid))       AS data_size,
       PG_SIZE_PRETTY(PG_TOTAL_RELATION_SIZE(relid) - PG_RELATION_SIZE(relid))
                                                     AS external_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
ORDER BY PG_TOTAL_RELATION_SIZE(relid) DESC,
         PG_RELATION_SIZE(relid) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 select uv.a tablename, pg_size_pretty(uv.b) sizepretty 
 from (select tb.tablename a, pg_table_size('schemaname.'||tb.tablename::text) b 
        from pg_tables tb 
        where tb.schemaname ilike 'schemaname' 
        order by 2 desc
       ) uv
```

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable if you include an explanation as to why the suggested approach is helpful.

Comment: Its similar to horse's answer, just doing sorting by size with pretty since sort view will be easy to look.

Comment: Please add that text to your Answer, using the Edit link in the "Answer" space. Then your contribution will conform to the StackOverflow guidelines (read a bit in the Help Center) :-)

Answer (score 3):

```sql
select table_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name));
```

`pg_total_relation_size` would include size of indexes as well as tables.
If you want only the table size, then `pg_relation_size` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this one (as it shows index size too)

```
SELECT
   relname  as table_name,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Total Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(relid)) as "Index Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) as "Actual Size"
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers here use `pg_size_pretty` which is very useful, but if you want to the output as a numerical value you can calculate this yourself like

```
SELECT tab_size /1024 AS size_kb
      ,tab_size /1024 /1024 AS size_mb
      ,tab_size /1024 /1024 / 1024 AS size_gb
      ,tab_size /1024 /1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS size_tb
  FROM 
      (
       SELECT pg_total_relation_size(relid) AS tab_size
         FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
        WHERE schemaname = 'your_schema' 
          AND relname = 'your_table'
      ) AS tabs;
```