# DB space usage outages

Tags: database, postgresql

Picked up that one of the DB is using a lot of space.

what is the best script or stored procedure which returns details information to see which table is using the most space?

is there a log maybe that shows which application added the data on the system logs?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question that has been asked previously: [postgresql list and order tables by size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738408/postgresql-list-and-order-tables-by-size).

TL;DR try the below:

```
select table_schema, table_name, pg_relation_size('"'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'"')
from information_schema.tables
order by 3 desc
```