# Postgres Database size and Table size sum do not match up

Tags: postgresql

I experienced a storage issue and then found that my database was taking up 300GB using:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database()))
```

Looking at the sum size of my schemas for this database, it only takes up 126 GB, which is 42%:

```
SELECT
   pg_size_pretty(sum(total_size)::bigint) as "total",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(relation_size_main)::bigint) as "main",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(relation_size_fsm)::bigint) as "fsm",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(relation_size_vm)::bigint) as "vm",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(relation_size_init)::bigint) as "init",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(table_size)::bigint) as "table",
   pg_size_pretty(sum(external_size)::bigint) as "external_size",
   (sum(total_size) / pg_database_size(current_database())) * 100 as percentage
FROM (
  SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname as schema_name,
     pg_total_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as total_size,
     pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid, 'main') as relation_size_main,
     pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid, 'fsm') as relation_size_fsm,
     pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid, 'vm') as relation_size_vm,
     pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid, 'init') as relation_size_init,
     pg_table_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as table_size,
     pg_total_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) - pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) as external_size
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
) t;
```

Which returns:

```
"total","main","fsm","vm","init","table","external_size","percentage"
"126 GB","97 GB","63 MB","17 MB","0 bytes","99 GB","29 GB",41.91348045761441753100
```

So what takes up the other 58%?

**NOTE:** Doing a `pg_dump`, clearing the `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` directory, restarting the server and reloading the SQL dump does solve this problem. **But this is not a valid production solution**.

**Additional Info**:
I am using the Postgres Docker container and have stopped it multiple times in the past few months since it was crippling my laptop.

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418679/1321908) and [this site](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) for helping with table size extraction.

Comment: Other database objects??

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe like what though, I'm hitting a blank this Monday morning

Comment: Hmm, yes, they must all be in `pg_class`. What may be left is orphaned temporary files or orphaned data files left behind from a crash during something like `VACUUM (FULL)`. Have there been any crashes?

Comment: I use the postgres docker and have often stopped it manually, so it could have happened then. Running a `VACUUM FULL` now to see if it makes a difference

Comment: If it is really orphaned files, that won't help. These files are hard to find.

Comment: Do you think I should do a dump, clean and restore? Sucks though, since this is the 3rd time this is happening

Comment: Yes, that would get rid of any orphaned files that remain from a crash. If I were you, I would make sure that PostgreSQL stops cleanly when you stop the container.

Comment: I think you can find your answers here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121804/what-parts-make-up-pg-database-size or here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109092/how-to-reclaim-space-taken-by-an-index-that-partially-built-and-was-terminated-b

Comment: Hi @tukan, great! Could you please mark this question as a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/109092/207343

Comment: You are welcome,  I thought that the main topic here is the dirty shutdown.  It is not possible to mark it as duplicate when it is not directly on SO, but on SE.  I don't know how to deal with such situation...

Comment: I guess I should've posted it there, my bad

Comment: You are welcome to post your comment as an answer

Comment: I'll do that for future reference, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be connected to the dirty shutdown.

The solution is posted on *dba stackexchange*: [How to reclaim space taken by an index that partially built and was terminated by a power outage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/109092/207343)

Should you suffer the same issue, check it  for solution.